# Javascript - sendkeys to proper dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vb.net

I'm a bit lost as to starting the code for my scenario.

I allow the user to create divs dynamically by clicking on an add new div button and remove div button. Therefore, the user could be focused inside any div on the page and I need to make the keypress event send to the correct div.

I have some buttons to insert Mathml on the left of the screen. I want to be able to click on the button and for the Mathml code to appear in the div the user is currently focused in.

From what I've read, I believe I have to attach an event listener to each div as it is created and remove it when the user removes the div (I maintain an index of the divs).

How do I send the keypress event from the button to the div the user is in without losing focus on the div and making sure the Mathml goes into the correct div?

I know in vb or C# .net it is a 2 second job but javascript seems like a real nightmare for this type of functionality.

Any help/pointers/tips etc.. would be most welcome.

Comment: Don't you have any examples of code or even some code you tried, just to see that you have done something, other than ask for the solution.

Comment: I'm stuck at the start here. I'm not really looking for code but more the approach I should take. I would like to know Step 1 - add event lister Step2. Add button Click event etc.. and figure it out from there. At the moment I'm lost on even how to start this. Here is my site if you want to see the fucntionality www.betamaths.eu

Comment: You have buttons, yet you are talking about keypress, do you mean `onClick`?  Do you realise by default `divs` can not receive focus or handle the `onblur` event which in this instance could handle the last "focused" div? Perhaps some code with what you have tried so far will clarify. Better still provide a snipet, the `<>` button on the SO editor

Comment: I meant onclick.. yes. I've posted the website address above www.betamaths.eu. The major issue I was having was actually where to start. Javascript is the worst language by far for trying to meddle around and get something working to show others. I have an answer below that I'm expanding on. Thanks for pointing out the pitfall with divs there.

Comment: You're next issue will probably be inserting at the last cursor position in your editor. I'm going to recommend you at least look at replacing what you are using with one that is still actively updated.  Try http://ckeditor.com/ which is very popular out there in the interwebs.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll swap editors to save me the inevitable pain coming my way in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I created this fiddle for you the get a look at how a possible solution could look.

https://jsfiddle.net/1u0uw0df/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
</div>
<button type="button" id="AddBtn">
Add
</button>
<button type="button" id="RemoveBtn">
Remove
</button>
```

**JQuery**

```
var No = 0;
var focusedElement;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').on('click','div',function() {
        focusedElement = this;
    });

    $('#AddBtn').on('click',function() {
        $('#container').append('<div>Test'+No+'</div>');
        No++
    });

    $('#RemoveBtn').on('click', function() {
        focusedElement.remove();
    });
});
```